# Insufficient storage message when attempting to install app

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sd-card, insufficient-memory

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S2. I have been trying to download apps, but get the insufficient storage message even though I have enough space free. However, the internal storage is almost full (200 MB remaining). Below is the amount of storage space which is used on my phone:

Internal Storage: Used: 1.8GB/2.0GB
Device Storage:   Used: 3.9GB/11.5GB
SD Card Storage:  Used: 4.0GB/7.4GB

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me sometimes when I uninstall any apk, and try to reinstall it. I use to search for some residual files of the prior apk, and android said you that you don't have space but actually is that it can't install the apk, it can't overwrite the residual files.

Maybe this is your case. It always fix this situation for me.