# Insufficient storage when attempting to download app

Tags: insufficient-memory, lg-g3

I got my new lg g3 and when i try to download something it says that there is insufficient space on the device. I looked up some solutions and google play services doesn't let me uninstall updates. are there other solutions? Btw i have about 8 gb of storage left

Comment: i added the [insufficient-memory](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory) [tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) to your question. Try taking a look there there for more tips and info.

Comment: Please see: [Insufficient storage message when attempting to install app](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/90210/16575) / [“Insufficient storage” when trying to install new app](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/23010/16575) and, as Ryan recommended, the [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where your phone is saving your downloads to, it may have insufficient space there (most likely the internal storage). Then your system may have already notified you that the system may misbehave and you should clear some storage.
 If not, then your storage may be messed up and the system is not allowed to write to a specific folder (I don't know what you try to download and what you use to download that).